# How to add context data to Django CreateView when form is valid

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, django-class-based-views

Using Django, I have a page with a form that is rendered using `CreateView`. The `success_url` is the same url as the original form. When the form is submitted and is valid, I want to insert some data into the context.

I'd like to know the most flexible and clear way to add this context data, because the example below (which works) feels sub-optimal for such a (presumably) common task. I'm looking for a more general solution that using `SuccessMessageMixin`.

```py
class DemoView(CreateView):
    template_name = "request-demo.html"
    form_class = DemoForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("base:demo")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        create_and_send_confirmation_email(form)
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(success_message=True))
```

Comment: If the form is submitted and valid, this will result in a redirect (to implement the Post/Redirect/Get architectural pattern) so there is *no* context to render.

Comment: I don't understand - the code snippet works. I see that it redirects, and the context is updated as expected, but I want to know if there is a better way of achieving this than the code snippet above.

Comment: it violates the Post/Redirect/Get pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get A successful POST request should *not* render a response, but return a redirect.

Comment: oh I see. Thank you.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem My form doesn't go to the `get_absolute_url()`. It stays at the same page. So I wondered if I could add a context saying "Form submitted".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most generically you will define the succcess_url to be the DetailView of the object you have just created. In fact, if you do not define a success_url at all, the default `get_success_url` will return

```
url = self.object.get_absolute_url()
```

which is commonly the same thing.

If you want to do something special for a newly created object you might

1. Redirect to a different URL, such as a subclass of your object DetailView with a custom `get_context_data` method and/or template name. Or possibly, somewhere completely differerent.
2. Interrogate the newly created object (in the template and/or get_context_data method) to establish in some application-specific way that it is indeed newly created.